# Solr or other choices

Tags: linux, solr

I have see SolR working on my PC and I could Index and search better. But I have 360 MB linux virtual machine, I want to run a web site on pylons.. what is the best search engine you can recommend.

So far, my linux box is clean from java installation. Is using Solr is overkill for 360 MB linux machine? I could see, I have 160 MB free when running website app server, nginx, memcached with 1 years :-).

I can increase the memory shortly.. I want better search options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xapian (http://www.xapian.org) is a good option for Python, it's very fast and simple to get set up with.

An interesting, pure Python new kid on the block is Whoosh (http://whoosh.ca/) although I've heard nothing about how well it performs in production.